# How to get the data from cshtml for controller action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have make the MVC website connection with database. the action in controller has been created as DeleteButton(idSelect) and it delete the data with id which is the prime key, and return the action of this page.

```
<button >Delete</button>
@foreach (var item in Model)
 {
      <tr class='clickable-row'>
           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
           </td>
      </tr>
  }
```

and i have js code when I click a row add class selected to tr, and only one row can be selected.
but what can i do to call this action in controller?

```
onclick="window.location='@Url.Action("DeleteButton", "Home", new { idSelect = 10000 })'"
```

I put this on button for testing and it works well. but I wanna get the id in the row with class selected to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd change your implementation to use a Jquery selector and an Ajax post something like the below.

Add your button with a html tag and add the "id" to the data attribute.

```
<input id="btnDelete" type="button" class="button" value="Run Script" data-id="@item.id"/>

$(document).on('click', 'button', function () {    
    var id= $(this).data("id");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/DeleteButton/",
        data: {idSelect:id}
     });
});
```

So the above JQuery will handle any button click, take the id associated with that buttons data-id attribute and post it to your controller/action with param called "idSelect"

Hope that helps
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the clickable row class on  tag.just render the action link. it will call your DeleteButton action method in Home controller

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
 {
      <tr>
           <td>
               @Html.ActionLink("Delete","DeleteButton", "Home", new { id = 10000 })
           </td>
      </tr>
  }
```